# Web scraping with DataMiner Chrome extension: Xpath variable

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm using the DataMiner Chrome extension to scrape data from a website. In Chrome, I'm using the Inspect Element > right click on element in Inspector > Copy XPath method to generate the XPaths for the data I need. This works great, but when I run the scrape, I'm getting the first entry of results repeated over and over.

Upon inspecting the second result and copying the XPath, I noticed there's a sequential number in the ID. Here are the XPaths for the first data point:

```
Entry 1 Company: //*[@id="Repeater_Results_ctl01_tCell1"]/h3/b/a
Entry 2 Company: //*[@id="Repeater_Results_ctl02_tCell1"]/h3/b/a
```

Can I insert a variable for the sequential number? Or is there a better way to go about it?

Here's an example page:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablelist" id="TsTable">
<tr>
   <th class="col1">Organization</th>
   <th>
      <div class="tCol2">Location</div>
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="Repeater_Results_ctl01_tCell1" class="tCell1">
      <h3><b><a href="/organization-search/details.aspx?slne=8118" target="_blank">Organization A</a></b></h3>
      <span class="nm">John Doe</span></h3>
      <p style="margin-bottom:0"><b>Phone:</b> 555-123-4567<br /><span class="webp"><b>Web: </b><a href="http://www.companya.com" target="_blank">www.companya.com</a></span><br />
      </p>
      <div class="locMobile"><b>LOCATION</b><br />
         <span style="white-space:nowrap">Anywhere,&nbsp;USA</span> <br />
         12345<br />
         <small><strong>0 miles</strong></small>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td id="Repeater_Results_ctl01_tCell2" class="tCell2a">
      <div class="tCell2"><b>LOCATION:</b><br />
         <span class="nw">Anywhere,&nbsp;USA</span><br />
         12345<br />
         <small><strong>0 miles</strong></small> 
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="Repeater_Results_ctl01_tCell4" colspan="2" class="tCell4a">
      <p><b>Services:</b> XYZ Services</p>
      <p><strong>Locations:</strong> Anywhere, USA</p>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="Repeater_Results_ctl02_tCell1" class="tCell1">
      <h3><b><a href="/organization-search/details.aspx?slne=2982" target="_blank">Organization B</a></b></h3>
      <span class="nm">Jane Dough</span></h3>                    
      <p style="margin-bottom:0"><b>Phone:</b> 555-123-9876<br /><span class="webp"><b>Web: </b><a href="http://www.organizationb.com" target="_blank">www.organizaionb.com</a></span><br />
      </p>
      <div class="locMobile"><b>LOCATION</b><br />
         <span style="white-space:nowrap">Somewhere,&nbsp;USA</span> <br />
         12345<br />
         <small><strong>6.7 miles</strong></small>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td id="Repeater_Results_ctl02_tCell2" class="tCell2a">
      <div class="tCell2"><b>LOCATION:</b><br />
         <span class="nw">Somewhere,&nbsp;USA</span><br />
         12345<br />
         <small><strong>6.7 miles</strong></small> 
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="Repeater_Results_ctl02_tCell4" colspan="2" class="tCell4a">
      <p><b>Services:</b> ABC Services</p>
      <p><strong>Locations:</strong>Somewhere, USA</p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **contains** method, like this

```
    //*[contains(@id, "_tCell1")]/h3/b/a
```

Comment: Thanks Tasawer! Although the suggested XPath is still pulling the data for the first record over and over.

I got closer with:
`*[1]/h3/b/a`

But this isn't properly separating the other data values, which I think share formatting styles. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I was able to get the `[1]/h3/b/a` method to work. Thank you!